# injection of $window in angular, what for?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window, code-injection

what is the use of the $window injection with Angular ?

for instance ,

```
var myController = function ($scope, $window) {

   // window is still available here
};
myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known best practice to avoid using global variables when possible. Therefore, Angular provides you with a valid 'angular' way option to get the window object inside your code as a service. It is incredibly useful for tests to have that option.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly for testability  purpose as stated in [Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

> While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes
>   testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we
>   always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be
>   overridden, removed or mocked for testing.